# Keep object as string in json deserialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I have a class with some fields and extra data of type string that will store a json object. I want it to not be deserialized, but after looking for more than an hour, the only thing I found was:

```
@Expose(deserialize=false)
```

But It doesn't work.

The following is an example:

```
public class Employee implements Serializable
{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Expose
    public Long id;
    @Expose
    public String name; 
    ... some more fields

    @SerializedName("extraData")
    @Expose(deserialize = false)
    public String extraData;



}
```

Then on my service I do the following:

```
    final GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();

    final Gson gson = builder.create();

    Employee emp = gson.fromJson(json, Employee.class);
```

The object I am receiving from the frontend is:

```
{
 "id":1,
 "name": "John Doe", 
 "extraData": {"someField1":"someValue1","someField2":"someValue2"}
}
```

And I get this error:
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 48 path $.extraData

When I just want to get "extraData" as an string with the value

```
{"someField1":"someValue1","someField2":"someValue2"}
```

Other solutions are not accepted because it is the spec i was given.

Comment: What about? `"{\"someField1\":\"someValue1\",\"someField2\":\"someValue2\"}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `TypeAdapters` for this and then add the `TypeAdapter` into your gson builder during the object creation.

https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html

Answer (score 1):

It does not harm if you change the type of `extraData` like (assuming it is possible and the extra data follows the pattern you described)

```
public Map<String, String> extraData;
```

and compose a `String` of it.

Still what Jaron F suggested might be better in whole. For using type adapter see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47859839/6413377)